# How do you read cURL request and how to make it with retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, curl, retrofit2, okhttp

How to make `@Get` in retrofit with this curl underneath?

```
curl -X GET https://myapidocumentation/device -d "id=[MY_ID]" -H "Authentication: [API_KEY]" --cookie "auth_key=[AUTH_KEY]" -G
```

This is my code so far, but it doesn't work.

```
interface Api {
    @GET("device")
    suspend fun getDetails(@Query("id") id: String, @Header("auth_key") auth_key: String): DetailsResponse
}
```

I get 401 response.
Thank for advice.

Comment: Did you read the documentation of curl (https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html)? What about Retrofit (https://square.github.io/retrofit/)? You're missing the authentication header from the curl (`Authentication: [API_KEY]`) in your Retrofit definition for starters.

Comment: Thank you so much it is more clear for me. IMO it's @ Query, @ Header, @ Query, but it doesn't work anyway.
For me it is a weird situation in intercept I have different token and in other places I log another token, why like this? Interceptor could change token? I take my token from share preferences for every case and it is different. I change for this and still 401. :(

Comment: I even added new header in interceptor like one is with Authorization second is with Authentication. still nothing

Comment: It's difficult to say what's wrong. Try to remove the interceptor for now and hardcode your values instead of adding more complexity to your problem by using an interceptor as well. If you're using an authenticator remove that as well for now. The interceptor can only change the token if you do something in there.